# (C++) Input checker does not work properly

Tags: c++, loops

I created a loop using the "placeholder" variable just to create a loop so that I can use "continue" with the if statement, which is supposed to give an error message and restart the loop if a number outside of the values (1-7) is entered, but it does not work. Any help is appreciated!

```
void PlayerOne(char d[ROW][COLUMN], int r[COLUMN])
{
    int rtemp, ctemp, mover;
    bool placeholder = true;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter your mover (X): "; cin >> mover; cout << endl;

        if ((mover < 1) && (mover > 7))
        {
            cout << "ILLEGAL INPUT DETECTED" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        rtemp = r[mover];
        ctemp = mover - 1;

        d[rtemp][ctemp] = 'X';

        r[mover]--;

        if (placeholder == true)
        {
            break;
        }

    } while (placeholder == true);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you think of a number that is both less than 1 and greater than 7?

Comment: out of the wrong test : your variable *placeholder* is useless, you just need a *for(;;)*, you also need to check *cin >> mover* success to not have an undefined behavior / an infinite loop

Comment: Your code won't loop, because `placeholder` is always `true`.  If you want the code to loop, get rid of the `placeholder` `if` statement.

Comment: also your *r[mover]--* is **very** strange, it can make *rtemp* negative and *d[rtemp]* to have an undefined behavior. Why the dangerous literal 7 rather than an expression using (at least) *COLUMN* ?

Comment: To answer bruno, I have a seperate function that sets all  r[ ] as 5, and it subtracts from there.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this line

> if ((mover < 1) && (mover > 7))

Is it possible to mover to be less than 1 and more than 7 at the same time? It will never comes true. I think you should change the binary operand (e.g. "||" by "&&") or change the comparissons. I hope this answer to be useful...

Comment: there are much more to say about the OP code, please do, currentely it is very short and already said in remark